# Execution order in Scala for/yield block

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, yield

I make three database calls (that all return `Future` values) using this syntax:

```
for {
  a <- databaseCallA
  b <- databaseCallB(a)
  c <- databaseCallC(a)
} yield (a,b,c)
```

The second and third call depend on the result of the first, but the two of them could be run in parallel.

How can I get `databaseCallC` to be issued immediately after `databaseCallB` (without waiting for the result `b`)?

Or is this already happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not happening currently - you have told the Futures to start one after the other. To parallelise the second and third call, you could use this:

```
for {
  a <- databaseCallA
  (eventualB, eventualC) = (databaseCallB(a), databaseCallC(a))
  b <- eventualB
  c <- eventualC
} yield(a,b,c)
```

This will start both the computation of b and c as soon as a is available, and complete once all three are available with the triple

Comment: The extra line with the eventuals is required, I assumed? No direct `(b,c) <- (callB, callC)`?

Comment: It is required, since the expression `(callB, callC)` is of type `Tuple2[Future, Future]`, which your for comprehension will not be able to deal with

Comment: I wonder is it possible to use `sequence` here? It may not be as elegant as this solution, but is probably more generic.

Comment: You could certainly use something like `aAndB <- Future.sequence(Seq(dbCallB(a), dbCallC(a)))` - but you would need to decompose the seqence again, which just adds notation.

Comment: @VictorMoroz You can extract sequence in one line `for { Seq(a, b) <- Future.sequence(Seq(dbCallB(a), dbCallC(a))) } `. Mind that it can lose types, if `dbCallB` and `dbCallC` have unrelated return types. In that case you'd have to retype them manually, e.g. `for { Seq(a: Int, b: String) <- ...`